# ExpressionToSQL produces invalid query

Tags: c#, expression, dapper, func, expressiontosql

I am using Dapper with [ExpressionToSQL](https://github.com/andygjp/ExpressionToSql/tree/master/src/ExpressionToSql) nuget package. I have a query as below:

```
Set = new Table{Schema = "Sch",Name = "tbl1"};
Columns = x => new { x.Id};
Conditions = x => x.Name== request.Name && x.Date == request.Date;

Where<TQueryIn, object> query = Sql.Select(Columns, Set).Where(Conditions);
...
connection.QueryAsync(query);
```

Where the value for `request.Name` is "T1" and `request.Date` is "20121020".

When I run the above-mentioned query, I get the following query:

```
SELECT a.[Id] FROM [Sch].[tbl1] AS a WHERE a.[Name] = @Name AND a.[Date] = @Date
```

As you see the `request.Name` and `request.Date`'s values are replaced with `@Name` and `@Date`!

What I need to see is:

```
SELECT a.[Id] FROM [Sch].[tbl1] AS a WHERE a.[Name] = 'T1' AND a.[Date] = '20121020'
```

Definitely this is not a problem with Dapper and it is a problem with ExpressionToSQL package.

Is there any way to overcome this issue, and convert `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to a string value with above mentioned output?

Comment: So you want to introduce SQL-injection vulnerability, even when your tool is trying to protect you? Does your query not include the generated parameters?

Comment: @oerkelens I am open to use it as the tool provides, but I do not know how to feed that parameters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Dapper, but after looking at the tests in [ExpressionToSQL](https://github.com/andygjp/ExpressionToSql/blob/master/tests/ExpressionToSql.Dapper.UnitTests/ExtensionTests.cs) it seems that you can provide the parameters on the second argument of `QueryAsync`, therefore, I think this should work:

```
Set = new Table{Schema = "Sch",Name = "tbl1"};
Columns = x => new { x.Id};
Conditions = x => x.Name== request.Name && x.Date == request.Date;

Where<TQueryIn, object> query = Sql.Select(Columns, Set).Where(Conditions);
...
connection.QueryAsync(query, request);
```

Also found this, may be useful:
https://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-anonymous